# ORA-56721: I/O data limit exceeded - session terminated

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql

I am executing a SQL select query from my Java program to fetch the record, sometimes this query runs properly but sometimes it gives error as below.

I am Using Java 1.6 and Oracle 12c database.

```
Exception :: ORA-56721: I/O data limit exceeded - session terminated
```

Is it because of insert (from other program) and select both query running on same table at same time?

I tried to search for a solution in google but got below result

```
ORA-56721: I/O data limit exceeded - session terminated

Cause: The Resource Manager SWITCH_IO_MEGABYTES limit was exceeded.

Action: Reduce the complexity of the update or query, or contact your database administrator for more information.
```

Is there any way to handle this exception from Java side? Will increasing heap memory size of JVM during execution of program help to resolve this?

Comment: This error is an Oracle internal error. Nothing you do in Java will alter it. You'd probably get better answers to this question on http://dba.stackexchange.com. Best of luck.

Answer (score 3):

Your session is being terminated because it is using too many resources and affecting the rest of the system (i.e., it's a disk hog).  The solution isn't to allow your query to consume more resources but to refactor your query to be more efficient.

If the work it is doing is that intensive you may want to consider breaking the single query into multiple steps.

Answer (score 2):

I got reason for issue in my Application , that at DB side it added a new feature called Oracle Resource Manager, which basically limits the infrastructure resources(Disk IO, Memory, CPU) for non-application users. and I am using non-application user to Query.